# Show the independence between two i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let X,Y are independent random variables with equal distrbution (identically distributed). Show, that
E(X| X + Y ) = E(Y |X + Y ) = (X + Y) / 2

Comment: How does the title of the question relates to the question?

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry,  we have $E(X\mid X + Y) = E(Y \mid X+Y)$ (good exercise to formally justify this with the definition of conditional expectation).

Hence $X+Y = E(X+Y\mid X+Y) = E(X\mid X+Y) + E(Y\mid X+Y) = 2 E(X\mid X+Y)$

Thus $E(X \mid X+Y) = (X+Y)/2= E(Y \mid X+Y)$.